# Picture disapears when size reduced to mobile

Tags: html, css

When i size down to a mobile device my first `div` with the class 'armando' disappears .

All remaining `divs` resize correctly, i don't have any media queries targeting that `div`.

Here is my code below:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row padRight ">
        <div class="container-fluid armando col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
        <div class="container-fluid col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

        <div class="text-center"><h4>Local Amenities</h4>
        </div>

          <p class="marRL"><a href="https://pt-pt.facebook.com/PORTA10Hotdogs/" target="_blank">Porta 10 </a>is a little gem of a snack bar it's within a couple of minutes walk from the apartment.
          The owner Armando is a gentleman, very friendly and accommodating and will adjust any dish to suit you.<br>

          Really nice and clean venue, food and drinks are very cheap and they have a particularly good variety of hot dogs. There is plenty of other dishes to choose from including breakfast.

          If you are looking for a good value meal I couldn't recommend it more.
          <br>Maxi Pizza next door also do great pizzas for eating in or take away if you dont fancy going out.
          Then you have BC's a few doors down really nice portuguese resturant with great food and great prices.<br>
          The bus stop for the old Town is directly opposite on the other side of the road, making Porta 10 very handy for a swift one on the way down Town.
          </p>

        </div>
        <div class="mdframe container-fluid col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 porta10"></div>ter code here

   //CSS 
    .armando {
         background-image: url("../images/rsz_armando.jpg");
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         background-position: center;
         background-size: contain;
     }
```

Comment: Set some min-height to avoid disappearance of image. For more https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are showing the image using a background image, you need to specify the `min-height` of the `div` that is showing the image, especially as you have no content inside either.

Adding a `min-height` value will force the `div` to stretch resulting in showing the `background-image`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set min-height to class .armando please check below code:

```
.armando {
    background-image: url("../images/rsz_armando.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: This supposed to be comment and not answer read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Hello @Vikas, please apologise @Varsha for his lack of explanation. Perhaps if you copied and pasted OP's code and by adding the relevant `min-height` to it along with an explanation why it works, it would be the best way to answer the question.

Comment: Sure next time i will take care of this. thanks @VarshaDhadge for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for background image:

```
.armando {
    background-image: url("../images/rsz_armando.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;        
    min-height: 100px; /* Change this to your need
}
```

Comment: Hello @Shahaji, thank you for trying to answer this post. Please include a small explanation why `min-height` is necessary to OP.

Answer (score 0):

**Plese set min-height you want. also you forget some div to close so update following code into your existing code**

```css
.armando {
  background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/1000/500");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row padRight ">
    <div class="container-fluid armando col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
    <div class="container-fluid col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="text-center"><h4>Local Amenities</h4></div>
    </div>
    <p class="marRL"><a href="https://pt-pt.facebook.com/PORTA10Hotdogs/" target="_blank">Porta 10 </a>is a little gem of a snack bar it's within a couple of minutes walk from the apartment.
      The owner Armando is a gentleman, very friendly and accommodating and will adjust any dish to suit you.<br>

      Really nice and clean venue, food and drinks are very cheap and they have a particularly good variety of hot dogs. There is plenty of other dishes to choose from including breakfast.

      If you are looking for a good value meal I couldn't recommend it more.
      <br>Maxi Pizza next door also do great pizzas for eating in or take away if you dont fancy going out.
      Then you have BC's a few doors down really nice portuguese resturant with great food and great prices.<br>
      The bus stop for the old Town is directly opposite on the other side of the road, making Porta 10 very handy for a swift one on the way down Town.
     </p>
    </div>
  <div class="mdframe container-fluid col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 porta10"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly you do not need to repeat the `container-fluid` in all of your `div` so it is save to remove them. Only keep it in the parent div.

Then to fix the issue with your class `.armando` you just need to add a min-width/min-height which will make the image resize up until that point.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, very helpful as im a newbie!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to show a background image in a `div` with no content. I can't replicate your actual problem using the code you've posted. But here's one way to avoid losing sight of a div with no content.

NOTE: I had to edit your code slightly, to use a background image of some flowers, and to include the bootstrap library.

```css
.armando {
  background-image: url("https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/40000/velka/daisies-1362124729AqU.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}
.armando:empty::before{
  content:"\200B"; /*Make sure there's content in the div*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row padRight ">
        <div class="container-fluid armando col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
        <div class="container-fluid col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

        <div class="text-center"><h4>Local Amenities</h4>
        </div>

          <p class="marRL"><a href="https://pt-pt.facebook.com/PORTA10Hotdogs/" target="_blank">Porta 10 </a>is a little gem of a snack bar it's within a couple of minutes walk from the apartment.
          The owner Armando is a gentleman, very friendly and accommodating and will adjust any dish to suit you.<br>

          Really nice and clean venue, food and drinks are very cheap and they have a particularly good variety of hot dogs. There is plenty of other dishes to choose from including breakfast.

          If you are looking for a good value meal I couldn't recommend it more.
          <br>Maxi Pizza next door also do great pizzas for eating in or take away if you dont fancy going out.
          Then you have BC's a few doors down really nice portuguese resturant with great food and great prices.<br>
          The bus stop for the old Town is directly opposite on the other side of the road, making Porta 10 very handy for a swift one on the way down Town.
          </p>

        </div>
        <div class="mdframe container-fluid col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 porta10"></div>ter code here
```